# Dynamically build nested html table from datatable results

Tags: html, vb.net, recursion, datatable

I am having trouble making a nested table builder using vb.net code. I have a datatable storing everything with child-parent ids, and it would require the code to loop recursively and build the tables dynamically from a user input. Unfortunately, I can only get it to loop through and output all the data (not nested). I need help with "if (child has parents) then make nested table" and repeat. The code below is what I have to output all rows. It does not evaluate if item has parents. That is what I need help with. My code I tried would only go one level deep (not recursively). Any help would be appreciated.

```
     Public Sub tablebuilder(ByRef tDataTable As DataTable)
         Response.Write("<table>")
         Response.Write("<tr><th><Child></th><th><Parent></th></tr>")
         For Each row As DataRow In tDataTable.Rows
             Response.Write("<tr><td>row.Item("IMA_ItemName_CHILD").ToString</td>")
            Response.Write("<td>row.Item("IMA_ItemName_PARENT").ToString</td></tr>")
         Next
         Response.Write("</table>")
    End Sub
```

Any help would be awesome. Stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Got it finally. Must be my 100th guess....didn't think it would let me call the sub inside the sub itself, but it worked. Moved the table calls outside, but new tr are in the correct place (nested)

```
Public Sub MakeSimpleTable(ByRef pDataTable As DataTable, ByRef viewer As String)

    Response.Write("<tr>")
    Response.Write("<th>Parent Id</th>")
    Response.Write("<th>Parent Name</th>")
    Response.Write("<th>QPA</th>")
    Response.Write("</tr>")

    Dim sortOrder As String = "IMA_ItemID_PARENT ASC"
    Dim rows() As DataRow = pDataTable.Select("IMA_ItemID_CHILD = '" & viewer & "'", sortOrder)
    Dim CP() As DataRow

    For Each row As DataRow In rows
        RowBuilder(row)
        viewer = row.Item("IMA_ItemID_PARENT").ToString
        CP = pDataTable.Select("IMA_ItemID_CHILD = '" & viewer & "'", sortOrder)
        If (CP.Length > 0) Then
            MakeSimpleTable(pDataTable, viewer)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub RowBuilder(ByRef row As DataRow)

    Response.Write("<tr>")
    Response.Write("<td>")
    Response.Write(row.Item("IMA_ItemID_PARENT").ToString)
    Response.Write("</td>")
    Response.Write("<td>")
    Response.Write(row.Item("IMA_ItemName_PARENT").ToString)
    Response.Write("</td>")
    Response.Write("<td>")
    Response.Write(row.Item("PST_QtyPerAssy").ToString)
    Response.Write("</td>")
    Response.Write("</tr>")

End Sub

Public Sub CreateSearch()

    Dim mySQL As String = "editted"
    Dim myTable_Items As DataTable = GetData(mySQL)
    Dim viewer As String = mySearch

    viewer = mySearch

    Response.Write("You searched ")
    If Len(mySearch) > 0 Then Response.Write(mySearch) Else Response.Write("everything.")
    Response.Write("<br /><br />")
    Response.Write("<table border = '1'>")
    MakeSimpleTable(myTable_Items, viewer)
    Response.Write("</table>")

End Sub
```